# How to set dynamic width & height of a view in autolayout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, autolayout

I have a UIView in my super view.I have set it some constraints.Now I want the size of view should be different on different devices.If I set the fix width & height then I get the wrong result.I have tried to user aspect ratio but that make a view too big or too small on multiple devices.

I want the height & width should increase in equal proportion that it must look same all devices.I want to have flexible height and width of the view.Please tell how to do this?

Here is the image
   [image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: place the screen shots

Comment: See image link please

Comment: If you want your width and height to be flexible, don't set the width and height constraint. 
Set the top, leading, trailing and bottom constraint.

Comment: @Maverick Issue is i want a my view to be in center of the main view & then make it's height & width flexible.

Comment: can u email me the nib file and corresponding class so i will fixed it out and will send u

Comment: what is your email id?

Comment: hadanischal@gmail.com email me then

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 3):

Use Size Classes. It helps to have different settings for different devices. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial 
https://youtu.be/IwSTXY0awng?t=2m12s

Comment: I know size classes is one of the way to do that.So it means i can't do without size classes.I am using base all value size class as of now @Andrei Luca

Comment: Similar way i have more contents like image view & labels other components i want their different size. So then do i need to use size classes.

Comment: I want to have diffrent view size on iphone 4 & iphone 6 but size class for them is same

Comment: in this case make some IBOutlets to constraints that control the views, and change them programatically very easy, for each device. You can even animate this constrains.

Comment: Well i was expecting if i don't have to use any code.In realease of xocde 6 & iOS 8 we don't need write code & can achieve this by using story boards.

Answer (score 2):

[image]The most simple way is create a Outlet of your `width` and `height` constraint.

Then dynamically change it in `viewDidLoad` according to phone.

To check which phone it is u can check the device height like `480` for iPhone 4S ,`568`for iPhone 5,5S and etc

```
@interface ScoreListViewController (){
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

@end



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Set the value according to your requirement
if(4S){
self.heightConstraint.constant=100;
}

 }
```

Comment: Well that's what i don't want why i can't i change the view height & width using only story board & make them dynamic @muku

Comment: u can't my friend,u can't do this with storyboard

Comment: then why they say we don't need to code if we use xcode 6 & iOS 8. @muku

Comment: there are certain scenarios where we have to use different methods.tats why apple has given both the methods

Comment: Thats really difficult way to do.

Comment: its easy,u just have to create a outlet and set value

Comment: what's the role of xocde 6 & size classes then?

Comment: in my case I have a view that needs data-driven contents and the size won't be known until those contents are generated. at that point I can set the width constraint and height constraint's constants programmatically and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the screen shots as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> You will get the result as below

[image]

Comment: sir but the width of red view is not correct of all screen sizes.As you can see width is not fine.I want equal prorportion.This is the same problem i am facing

Comment: u mean width and height need to be equal

Comment: If you see the box in 4.7 inch screen i want that type box in all phone screens where as in 3.5 box height is tool small & width is also small.so i want that type of box in all the phone screens.

Comment: i doubt what i want is either possible or not using only story boards?

Comment: can you please provide me the help?

Comment: I think u need to place scroll view

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog [article](http://deltaaruna.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/autolayouting-for-dynamically-changing.html) about autolayouting for dynamically changing layouts.
For each screen size you can programmatically add the constraints.
Algorithm

1. Get the current device size
2. Get the required constraints according to the device size
3. Then programmatically add the constraints

Changing according to orientation

- Listen to the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notifiation
- Add new constraints according to the notification
- Then call setNeedsUpdateConstraints
  For more info and a example code, look at the blog article and [this](https://github.com/deltaaruna/AutolayoutTableViewCell) github repo