# Different size and alignment of view for different device widths

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

How would I achieve that a view spans over the device width on an iPhone 6 in portrait mode and on landscape having a maximum width of say 400px and be aligned to the right side?

Can this be achieved by using device classes and / or vary for traits? What I really want, is that the view adapts to the width of the device: if it is wider than 400px (because I rotated the device to landscape mode or because the app runs on an iPhone Plus or iPad) it should no longer span the width of the display but rather have a maximum width of 400px and sit on the right side. Maybe this can only be done by code?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set dynamic width & height of a view in autolayout in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777528/how-to-set-dynamic-width-height-of-a-view-in-autolayout-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I really want, is that the view adapts to the width of the
>   device: if it is wider than 400px (because I rotated the device to
>   landscape mode or because the app runs on an iPhone Plus or iPad) it
>   should no longer span the width of the display but rather have a
>   maximum width of 400px and sit on the right side.

This can be achieved by setting the following constraints to control the width and placement of your view.

1. Pin the view to the trailing edge of its superview with constant `0` and a priority of `1000`.
2. Pin the view to the leading edge of its superview with a constant of `0` and a priority of `750`.
3. Set a width constraint for the view, and make it *Less Than or Equal* to `400` with a priority of `1000`.

When viewed on an iPhone 6 in *portrait*, all three constraints are easily satisfied.

When viewed on an iPhone 6 in *landscape*, constraint 2 (which has the lower priority) is broken to satisfy the other 2 constraints.  *Auto Layout* will do its best to satisfy constraint 2 and will make the view as wide as possible without breaking the width constraint which is `400` units.

You will need other constraints for your view to establish its height and vertical position.

---

[image: constraints in Storyboard]

---

[image: gif showing running in the simulator]