# How to change the height of a UIImageView for smaller devices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I have a screen that does not translate well onto an iPhone 5 screen size. To make it work I want to change only the height of a UIImageView when the screen is shown on a iPhone 5. How can I use auto-constraints or Swift code to be able to do this?

Comment: If you are working with auto layout (which it sounds like you do), set multipliers (and possibly constants) for *all* devices. No need to code frames or for a specific size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set dynamic width & height of a view in autolayout in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777528/how-to-set-dynamic-width-height-of-a-view-in-autolayout-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding an outlet to your constraint and then updating the constant value at runtime depending upon your device.

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstant: NSLayoutConstraint!

self.heightConstant.constant = 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frame of UIImageView accordingly:

If iphone 5, then `imageView.frame = smallerFrame`

Else, `imageView.frame = biggerFrame`